# How can I remove a bound script from a Google Sheets Spreadsheet?

Tags: google-apps-script, google-api

I have a spreadsheet where I first created a bound script file (via Tools->Script Editor).  I then (at a later time) was exploring the File menu and hit Make A Copy.  I now get a "Select a project to open" with the original "myAddOns" and "Copy of myAddOns" as the choices.  I would like to remove the copy.  I found it in the scripts My Projects page, but when I try to remove it the original spreadsheet also gets removed.  (Pulled it back out of Google Drive Trash folder)

Am I stuck with this?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

It turns out that (as the project owner) using the File->Delete Project once I open the Script Editor works.  Not sure how I got messed up before.

Answer (score 0):

Turns out that all of us can forget how to do this. Thanks for asking the question. In the new editor, this feature is found in Project Details, then to the far right. Click the Trash Can that warns "Delete Project Forever". Yes, please. Hope this helps someone in the future.